# CKEditor issue not reading from cloud storage

Tags: ckeditor, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

After installing the Mandeeps Cloud Storage module, we have confirmed it is enabled as a connector. We have confirmed, using the DNN site assets the files are being read from Azure. We do have an issue with the CKeditor, reading files locally and not using the connector. Is there a setting or fix for this.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you contact Mandeeps' support team for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used the Mandeeps cloud storage but their knowlegdebase is pretty good and it seems to cover this topic

"you can use existing Azure folders by adding a folder of the same name in Add Folder TextBox in FileManger"

https://www.mandeeps.com/support/knowledgebase/cloud-storage-folder-types-windows-azure

there is also a default file location for the ckeditor that can be configured from the site settings page

[HTML editor manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PKBx.png)